# return a list of employees who report to a specified person

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I return a list of employees who report to another employee through outlook.

This searches through the global address list and if the username is found 'user' is equal to an exchange user object(I think).

When I run this it says user is an invalid qualifier but when I looked it up you are supposed to call the GetDirectReports function on an exchange user object.

```
Public olApp As Object
Public olNameSpace As Object

Dim Person As cEmployee
Set Person = New cEmployee
Dim Emp As cEmployee

Dim user As String
Dim olEntry
Dim userCollection As collection
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Set olGal = olNameSpace.GetGlobalAddressList
Set userCollection = New collection

For Each OlEntry In olGal.AddressEntries
   If olEntry.name = "Manager's Name" Then
      user = olEntry.GetExchangeUser()
      Exit For
   End If
Next olEntry

Dim iter
For Each iter In olEntry.GetDirectReports()
   Set Emp = new cEmployee
   userCollection.Add Emp
Next iter
```

I want a collection of cEmployee objects who report to the specified manager.

The error I am getting is

Run-time error '438'
Object doesn't support this property or method

```
Option Explicit
Private pName As String
Private pMail As String
Private pUserName As String
Private pPhone As String

Public Property Get name() As String
    name = pName
End Property

Public Property Let name(user As String)
    pName = user
End Property

Public Property Get mail() As String
    mail = pMail
End Property
Public Property Let mail(email As String)
    pMail = email
End Property

Public Property Get userName() As String
    userName = pUserName
End Property
Public Property Let userName(name As String)
    pUserName = name
End Property

Public Property Get phone() As String
    phone = pPhone
End Property

Public Property Let phone(number As String)
    pPhone = number
End Property
```

Comment: Where is the class code for `cEmployee`? The last `For` loop looks like it's just adding empty objects to a collection - what are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: Do I need a constructor for the cEmployee class? sorry this is the first time using vba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

olEntry.GetExchangeUser returns an `ExchangeUser` object, but you are assigning it to a string.

```
Dim user As Object
...
set user = olEntry.GetExchangeUser()
```

Once you have the `ExchangeUser` object, call `GetDirectReports` to get a list of the users who report to the given user.

Comment: So each 'iter' would be an exchangeUser?

Comment: Yes, it would be.